# Print Dialog Does not show up in Crystal Report Viewer ... giving error

Tags: .net, asp.net, crystal-reports, reportviewer

WE developed system integrated with crystal Reports, with Crystal Report viewer on page. but the problem is we hosted it on 32 bit server but when access it and try to print the report it gives the error and does show any dialogue. we have installed full crystal report version with License but error is there.

I tried to find but no success, one person said on net that if Crystal Report viewer is in updatePanel, but in my case is not there is no updatepanel on this page even.

[image]

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you have the following directories in the root of your site (the css, html, images and js directories can be found on your development pc under Program Files\Business Objects....):

[image]

I had the same issue whereby the print dialog, etc didn't work when deployed to our web servers and it was because the above directories and files were missing in the root of the web site.  I think it's primarily the js directory that's needed to get the print dialog to work but others will be needed for button images on the crystal report viewer, etc.